# Error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: objectType" when opening a VB.NET Windows Forms in designer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have Windows Forms App in VB.NET it runs fine, I added some code event manually, without designer, like this:

> Private Sub bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As System.Object,
>   e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click
>
> namesBindingSource.AddNew()
>
> End Sub

And one the Form1.Designer.vb, InitializeComponent method this code

> AddHandler Me.BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click, AddressOf
>   Me.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click

Now, even though the form runs fine, and the event is executed correctly; the form fails at design time with the error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: objectType
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.TypeDescriptionNode.GetRuntimeType(Type
>   objectType) at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptionProvider.GetRuntimeType(Type
>   reflectionType) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.MultiTargetingContextProvider.GetRuntimeType(Type
>   objectType) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.HandlesClauseManager.GetFieldType(String
>   fieldName, Type documentBaseType) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.HandlesClauseManager.GetReferencedComponentType(String
>   componentName, CodeTypeDeclaration codeTypeDecl,
>   ITypeResolutionService loader, IDictionary& cache) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.HandlesClauseManager.ParseHandlesClauses(CodeTypeDeclaration
>   codeTypeDecl, Boolean updateCache) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) at
>   System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements() at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   serializationManager) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost
>   host)

Now, I notice it doesn't happen if I bind the event by designer, instead of manually.

But I still need to do it manually, because it will eventually be generated by some DTE automation code.

Also if after the error I press the link "Ignore and Continue" it shows the form fine at design time, but why it is failing in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you fix this:

1. Go into the form code
2. Delete everything in between Public Class (your form name) and End Class.

Open the form designer.  Did it open normally?

If yes, you're on the right track.

Put the code back; little by little, keep removing code until your form opens.  The last code you deleted was the problem.

This happens when an event handler contains a reference to a non-existing object. For example, if you place a button on a form, create the Click event handler and then remove this button from the form.

Comment: thanks, your solution is a little elaborated (due to needing to add code little by little). That's way I posted the other answer.

Comment: what if you don't know the event that you need to remove the "handles" from?  In my case, I didn't have a binding source event like you did, but I still had the problem.

Comment: For my problem (for which I posted the question) all the event handlers must use the Handles keyword (that was the solution).

Comment: Wait... in your fix, you say you need the handles clause removed.  Now you're saying "all the event handlers must use the Handles keyword".  I'm confused.  Did you add "Handles blahblahblah", or did you remove the "Handles" keyword?

Comment: Yeah, look, there are two options equally valid in VB.NET
a) Use AddHandler to bind events to event handlers
b) Use Handles clause
You must use either one or another, blending both causes trouble for the Windows Forms Designer
I started using AddHandler because the code was translated from C# (there is no Handles there).

Comment: You can use both in one form; I can show you samples if you'd like.  If people don't want to change every event to "AddHandler", they can still use the Handles keyword.  The issue described that we're solving for is when a specific "handles" statement refers to a control no longer on the form.  My solution works no matter which way you prefer.  Your way only works if you want to stop using the Handles keyword.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Look, I know it fail in my scenario, If I have time to get back to this (which I cannot do now) I will reverify and check your claims, Until then, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found another cause of this as well...

Check the upper/lower case on your event names!  One of our controls got renamed, so it was CtlBlah instead of ctlBlah.  The event was still in lower case.  Switching it to proper case to match the actual control fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the code for the event needs to have the "Handles..." clause removed, like

> Private Sub bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As System.Object,
>   e As System.EventArgs)
>
> namesBindingSource.AddNew()
>
> End Sub

Now the Form opens correctly in the Designer right from the first time.

UPDATE: I had to instead add the handler with AddHandler statement.

Comment: No, no, no. @StevieTimes answer is the WTG. Your answer removes the event handlers - you know if you click **Ignore and continue** it removes all the event handlers and the form designer renders - but then you have effectively deleted all your events! Your answer suggests to do the *Ignore and continue* MANUALLY!

Comment: Sorry, but No, No events are deleted ever, they are still triggered, for further reference look at the code generated by the Windows Forms Template Wizard for VB.NET, for MySql for Visual Studio, see https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Comment: Your answer is to remove the *Handles* (ie Event subscription) from a binding Navigator, so you're deleting the event. Stevie's answer allows you to keep the forms event in tact.

Comment: Oh, and Stevie's answer was not a solution to my particular problem, In fact it turns out this designer error can happen under a lot of circumstances.

Comment: Again, @Jeremy, please check the reference code I give, the handler is added with addhandler (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx)